# Create css file based on dropdown selection

Tags: asp.net

I Use below website for my reference.

http://www.css3maker.com/

I want to create css file based on dropdown selection change in asp.net.

select Html tag from dropdown, then it is display output and based on that create css file.

Comment: Onselectedindexchanged event you can add cssclass and add corresponding style.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It's very ease to implenet. You сфт to use jQuery library:

HTML:

```
 <select id="chooser">
     <option>50</option>
     <option>100</option>
     <option>150</option>
 </select>
 <div id="theDiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
 $('#chooser').change( function() {
   $('#theDiv').css('width', $('#chooser').val() + 'px');
 });
```

CSS:

```
 #theDiv
 {
     background-color: #187236;
     height:50px;
     width: 50px;
 }
```

Working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJEPF/).

But to make a fully functional page, you have to do a lot more. Just open css3maker with developer tools(in most browsers it's F12 button) and do your search to find out how was it made.

Comment: I want css automatically generate based on selection.
is it possible through above code or jsfiddle.?